# check if input is empty set to zero in javascript

Tags: javascript

When the user delete the value in input using the `backspace` the function work correctly but if he delete the value and set a new number like 1 the new value is deleted and set again to zero.

```
<input type="text" id="txtField" value="0" ></input>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#txtField").keyup(function() {

    var v = $(this).val();

    console.log(v)
    if (v == "") {
      console.log(v)
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#txtField").val(0);
      }, 1000);

    }
  });
});
```

I don't know what is the problem in my code any help please?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2shadgtw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `setTimeout`. If the user clears the `input` and then enters a value in the next second, the function in `setTimeout` will still go off, setting the `value` to `0`.

Try checking the `input` inside the `setTimeout` instead, like this:

JavaScript

```
$("#txtField").keyup(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#txtField").val().trim().length === 0) {
            $("#txtField").val(0);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/2shadgtw/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `setTimeout`. Instead try mapping with these three events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtField").on("keyup change blur", function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "")
      $(this).val(0);
  });
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hm6e8hL/**

Comment: this don't work i can't change the default value it return to zero immediately

Comment: @Sora What exactly are you trying to do? What default value?

Comment: i mean the value 0 this is what i did : 1- if i remove the zero using back space the input still empty 
2- if i delete the 0 and put 1 the value return to 0

Comment: @Sora Did you see the there's no `</input>` for the `<input>` tag.

Comment: @Sora It was my mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: if the input is empty it's value should be zero . it is not working with me , try to delete the value using backspace you will see that the input remain empty

Comment: @Sora It works for me. When I press backspace or delete, and wait for a few secs, it returns to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `blur` event to do this rather than `keyup`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtField").on("blur", function() {
    if (!$(this).val().trim())
      $(this).val(0);
  });
});
```

If the input is empty when it loses focus - then give it a value 0.

else - do nothing.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/73q8p1k9/)

Comment: yes but if there is a submit button in the page and the user empty the input using backspace and click the button the value will be empty

Comment: @Sora Are you sure? Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/73q8p1k9/1/ - if you delete the contents of the textfield and then click on the button the blur event still takes place replacing the empty value with 0

Comment: it seem like i was mistaken i post my comment without testing the result .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is a bad solution. But ypu can use if-statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



 $("#txtField").keyup(function() {
var v = $(this).val();

console.log(v)
if (v == "") {
  console.log(v)
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(!$("#txtField").val()){
        $("#txtField").val(0);
    }
  }, 1000);

}


});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guv0c5ox/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using focusout() function. Try this

```
<input type="text" id="txtField" value="0" />

$("#txtField").focusout(function() {

var v = $(this).val();

console.log(v)
if (v == "") {
    $("#txtField").val(0);
}
});
```

It will set the value to zero on focus out if the field is empty.

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2shadgtw/7/)